# How to bind the attribute value with a variable in angular 8?

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm developing a virtual store and i need to make a comment with a logged user and save his id in my database.
so i need to pass the id of the logged user in the value attribute of my hidden input and update the model too. 
But when i click on the save icon ,i don't get the id in my model 
Can you help me with this?

This is my model in my ts file of the component

````
    comentario: '',
    producto_id: '',
    usuario_id: '',
    estado: '',
    created_at: new Date(),
    update_at: new Date(),
  } ``` 


This is one of my input 
``` <input type="hidden" name="usuario_id" (ngModelChange)="comentario.usuario_id" value="{{user.id}}" class="form-control" ng-init="comentario.usuario_id=user.id">``` 

I expect to see the element of the variable {{user.id}} in my model but the current is the default one of my model 

comentario: "ddsdsd"
​
created_at: Date 2019-06-28T11:39:40.014Z
​
estado: ""
​
producto_id: ""
​
update_at: Date 2019-06-28T11:39:40.014Z
​
usuario_id: "1" I expect to get this from my {{user.id}}
````

Comment: `ng-init` in angular seems weird is it a custom directive ?. Also use property binding  `[value]="somevariable"`

Comment: where ur user id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using (ngModelChange) i think the statement should be

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="comentario.usuario_id" [value]="user.id">
```

Another way of doing this is through [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)